# EF Max on Record By Value

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ado.net, entity-framework-4

I want to get the maximum record based on a field, but the Max() extension returns that given type.  Say this:

```
o.Max(i => i.CreatedDate) // returns date
```

Returns the maximum date value; I want to return the record itself like:

```
o.Max(i => i.CreatedDate) // returns the record with the maximum condition
```

Is there a method to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
o.OrderByDescending(i => i.CreatedDate).First()
```